# Pass paperclip image.url to JSON in a 'joins' query in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have here a query with joins.

```
def supported
    render json: @posts = @user.funders.joins(:post => :photos).select("campaigns.*, funders.*, photos.*").to_json
end
```

Model relationships:

`user` has many `funders`

`funder` belongs to `post`

`post` has many `photos`

Yes I'm getting the columns of `Photo` model from the object, but can't seem to get the `url` of the image.

```
0: Object
$$hashKey: "012"
anonymous: true
post_id: 10
category: "Fashion & Beauty"
created_at: "2014-08-22T10:09:26.001Z"
description: "Consequatur ab sapiente commodi officiis perferendis. Deleniti ut vel consequatur. Aut cupiditate rerum dicta sit quis."
donation_amount: "65792.0"
end_at: null
featured: false
funding_goal: "32119495.0"
id: 1
image_content_type: "image/jpeg"
image_file_name: "IMG_20140729_005405_Fotor.jpg"
image_file_size: 1074766
image_updated_at: "2014-08-22T10:09:22.913Z"
name: "Fintone"
pledge: null
quote: "Delectus repudiandae quia ut dicta ex recusandae suscipit. Deserunt accusamus autem. Officiis eos adipisci vel id asperiores. Quae deserunt et aut culpa."
reward_id: 49
slug: "fintone-1d4e8da8-db70-46c9-9c0c-0efef4d02871"
start_at: null
status: "captured"
stripe_error: Array[0]
stripe_token: "920375637268007711"
tagline: "Deleniti ipsa id illum ut."
updated_at: "2014-08-22T10:09:26.001Z"
user_id: 1
video_url: null
zip_code: "98116"
```

I've tried to select `photos.image` but ain't got it working:

```
render json: @posts = @user.funders.joins(:post => :photos).select("campaigns.*, funders.*, photos.image").to_json
```

Is there any possible way to include Paperclip image `url` to JSON?

I'm passing it as JSON object because I'm using AngularJS btw.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's kinda weird to answer my own question.

I finally found the solution. Use nested `include` and put `methods`

```
@funders = @user.funders.to_json(:include => {:post =>{:include => {:photos => {:methods=> :photo_url}}}})
```

In my `photo_url` method:

```
def photo_url
  image.url(:original)
end
```